# Has deja dup gone messy?

Tags: deja-dup

Deja Dup I used today but got this problem -

*Backup Finished
Could not backup the following files.  Please make sure you are able to open them.*

```
/home/anony/.config/enchant
/home/anony/.dbus
```

**Annex**

```
ls -al /home/anony/.config/enchant

total 24
drwx------  2 root  root  4096 Oct 19  2015 .
drwx------ 37 anony anony 4096 Nov 23 09:42 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root     0 Oct 19  2015 en_...dic
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root     0 Oct 19  2015 en_...exc


ls -al /home/anony/.dbus

total 20
drwx------  3 root  root   4096 Oct 19  2015 .
drwx------ 39 anony anony 12288 Nov 30 22:25 ..
drwx------  2 root  root   4096 Oct 19  2015 session-bus
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a Deja-Dup issue. Those dirs shouldn't be owned by root.

You can run this command to take ownership back:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.dbus ~/.config/enchant/
```

This will fix the immediate issue, but since we don't know the cause, the issue may return. Did you make any changes recently that might have caused this? Where you're able to run `ls` on the dirs without `sudo`, that means you're running a root shell. That may be related. **Update**: OP actually is using `sudo`.